# Non-nullable readonly references and empty private default constructor in C# result in warning CS8618

Tags: c#

Some of my C# classes don't have a default constructor by design. I'm used to declare an empty private default constructor to prevent the clients of my class from using the compiler-provided default one.

Now I've enabled non-nullable references in my C# project (`#nullable enable`) and this no longer works, I refer to the `CS8618` warning below:

```
#nullable enable

public sealed class Operation
{
    private readonly CancellationTokenSource _cts;

    private Operation()
    {
        // Warning CS8618 Non-nullable field '_cts' is uninitialized. 
        // Consider declaring the field as nullable.
       
        //_cts = null!;
    }

    public Operation(CancellationToken token)
    {
        _cts = CancellationTokenSource.CreateLinkedTokenSource(token);
    }

    ...
}
```

It appears, I now either have to initialize all non-nullable fields (with null-forgiving `null!`, I suppose?) or remove the non-default constructor altogether. What is an elegant way of solving this?

**Update to address the comments:**

Maybe I wasn't clear enough, so I'll try to fix that. I'm well aware that C# provides a default `public` parameterless constructor if I don't declare one explicitly. That's exactly why I do declare it, and make it `private`. *That prevent an object of type `Operation` to be constructed with a parameterless constructor*.
I also have a factory class:

```
public static class OperationFactory
{
    public static Operation* CreateOperation(CancellationToken token)
    {
        return new Operation(token);
    }
}
```

The clients of my class can do:

```
var operation = new Operation(token)
```

or

```
var operation = OperationFactory.CreateOperation(token)
```

But they are **not allowed** to do:

```
// this would create an object in invalid state
var operation = new Operation();
```

So previously, to impose these rules I just had to declare an empty [private parameterless constructor](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/private-constructors): `private Operation() {}`.

Now with `#nullable enable`, I can no longer have an *empty* private constructor. I now have to initialize all my non-nullable reference fields in both the private constructor (which is still never used, so this is a drawback), and the public constructor.

Because the private constructor is essentially never used, I thought there might be an elegant way to avoid duplicating such initialization code. Is there any?

Comment: what if you just remove the default constructor?

Comment: Unfortunately asking for the most elegant way is futile, as this turns into a fashion sense question. Work out the ways to achieve your task and pick your favourite

Comment: Possiblie duplicate: [Avoid CS8618 warning when initializing mutable non nullable property with argument validation](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60702710/12888024)

Comment: Please explain why you add the parameterless constructor in the first place. When you provide any constructor, the compiler will no longer generate the default parameterless constructor, and the class cannot be instantiated with `new` except by using one of the explicit constructors you provide. Your problem seems to be a direct result of the code having a constructor in it that it shouldn't have anyway. It's not at all clear why this problem needs solving.

Comment: @PeterDuniho, I've added a `private` parameterless constructor in the first place so the users of my library don't have a choice to create instances of my class in that way. I want them to always use a constructor that requires parameters.

Comment: _"I've added a private parameterless constructor in the first place so the users of my library don't have a choice to create instances of my class in that way"_ -- but you already have another constructor. Your users don't have a choice, whether or not you declare the parameterless one. **That's the whole point of my question**. Your stated reason for including the constructor doesn't actually explain the constructor, and calls into question the entire scenario.

Comment: @PeterDuniho, I also have a static method like `CreateOperation(CancellaionToken)` that creates an instance of this class using non-default constructor. The instances can only be create this way or using that non-default constructor. If I allowed to create `Operation` with default constructor, that object would have invalid state. Does it make sense?

Comment: _"The instances can only be create this way or using that non-default constructor"_ -- true, but so what? How does that explain that you've also included the private parameterless constructor? Your statement would've been just as true even if you don't include the private parameterless constructor.

Comment: @PeterDuniho, `Your statement would've been just as true even if you don't include the private parameterless constructor.` - No I don't think it would, because then whoever uses my class could do `new Operation()`. If I did NOT include a private parameterless constructor, there would be a default public one, provided by the compiler. I don't want that.

Comment: _"If I did NOT include a private parameterless constructor, there would be a default public one, provided by the compiler."_ -- that is simply wrong. It seems your question is based entirely on your false belief about the C# language. See [Parameterless Constructors](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/constructors#parameterless-constructors) _"**If you don't provide a constructor** for your class, C# creates one by default"_. You've provided a constructor, so no default constructor is created.

Comment: @PeterDuniho, I've updated the answer with more details, I hope it makes more sense now.

Comment: If your `CreateOperation` constructs an instance using the private parameterless constructor then the compiler is right, the `_cts` field will be `null`. You will have to decide how to handle this, either by always ensuring `_cts` has a value, or marking it as nullable.

Comment: You've edited your question to make it clear you still have a misconception of the parameterless constructor. The documentation says that if you don't provide a constructor (any constructor), a public parameterless one is added by default. However, you have a public constructor, with parameters. Since you have at least one constructor declared, no parameterless constructor will be added by the compiler, public or private. As such, you do not need to declare a private parameterless constructor to prevent `new Operation()`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There seems to be a misunderstanding here about what the documentation states.

Specifically, [the documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/constructors#parameterless-constructors) states:

> If you don't provide a constructor for your class, C# creates one by default that instantiates the object and sets member variables to the default values as listed in the Default values of C# types article.

Note that what it *doesn't* say is this:

> If you don't provide a **parameterless** constructor for your class, ...

If you declare any constructor at all, the parameterless one will not be added by the compiler.

As such, your class can be changed to this, by simply removing the private parameterless constructor:

```
public sealed class Operation
{
    private readonly CancellationTokenSource _cts;

    public Operation(CancellationToken token)
    {
        _cts = CancellationTokenSource.CreateLinkedTokenSource(token);
    }

    ...
}
```

Since you have a constructor there, `public Operation(CancellationToken token)`, the compiler will not add a parameterless constructor, and you will have prevented anyone from doing this:

```
new Operation()
```

---

On the flipside, if you actually *need* the parameterless constructor for your own code, then the compiler is right. The `_cts` field is going to be left with its default value which is `null`. In this case you will have to figure out what to do with that `null`, and likely tell the compiler "You're right, I'll mark it as such" to squelch the warning.

Comment: A great answer, thank you! And coming from C++, where a default constructor is always provided, for many years I thought the same is true for C#... I live and learn :)

Comment: On a side note, I was looking for something like   `[System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Compiler", "CS8618")]` to apply to that private constructor, but that didn't work. I suppose if I really needed that, `#pragma warning disable CS8618` would be the best option, apart of doing the actual initializations.